# Value For Variable Not Overwritten When Using Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking

Apologies if I may be misunderstanding how Mockito works, but I'm trying to test for the case when one of my properties is null, setting it through mockito but it won't overwrite that unless I set the value for the whole object as null or make into a method and mock that instead and with the use of a spy.

Please let me try to better explain this with my code.

This is my class and the piece I want to test for. I'm checking the case where something wrong happens on saving a follower to a user so that is not set and returned empty. To be honest, I'm also not sure if it makes sense to test this with an if or whether I should be catching some exception here. But back to the original problem, the followerEntity object is always being created with the params for userTo and userFrom and this is what I'm trying to have mockito overwrite as null on the save call but in a way that it would return the other values for the user object. I'm not too sure, however, where I may be getting this wrong.

```
    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Override
    public void followUser(UUID fromId, UUID toId) throws FollowerNotFoundException {

        Optional<UserEntity> userEntityOptionalFrom = userRepository.findById(fromId);
        Optional<UserEntity> userEntityOptionalTo = userRepository.findById(toId);

        if (userEntityOptionalFrom.isEmpty() || userEntityOptionalTo.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException("No user found with this id");
        }

        UserEntity userEntityTo = userEntityOptionalTo.get();
        UserEntity userEntityFrom = userEntityOptionalFrom.get();

        Set<FollowingRequestEntity> followingRequestEntities = new HashSet<>();
        FollowingRequestEntity followingRequestEntity = FollowingRequestEntity.builder().userSenderEntity(userEntityFrom).userReceiverEntity(userEntityTo).build();
        followingRequestEntities.add(followingRequestEntity);

        userEntityTo.setFollowedByEntity(followingRequestEntities);

        userEntityTo = userRepository.save(userEntityTo);
        
        
        if (userEntityTo.getFollowedByEntity() == null || userEntityTo.getFollowedByEntity().isEmpty()) {
            throw new FollowerNotFoundException("Follower Not Found");
        }
    }

   public UserEntity setFollower(UserEntity userEntityTo, UserEntity userEntityFrom) { // The tests work if calling and mocking this instead
        Set<FollowingRequestEntity> followingRequestEntities = new HashSet<>();
        FollowingRequestEntity followingRequestEntity = FollowingRequestEntity.builder().userSenderEntity(userEntityFrom).userReceiverEntity(userEntityTo).build();
        followingRequestEntities.add(followingRequestEntity);

        userEntityTo.setFollowedByEntity(followingRequestEntities);
        
        return userEntityTo;
    }
```

This is what I have for my test. As you can see, I've tried both when..Return() and doReturn() and also forcing the follower entity values to null, but when debugging my user object it always shows the FollowerBy property populated and not null.

```
    @Test
    void testFollowUser_ThrowsExceptionWhenFollowerIsFound() {

        UUID userFromId = randomUUID();
        UUID userToId = randomUUID();
        UserEntity userEntityFrom = getUserEntity();
        userEntityFrom.setId(userFromId);

        UserEntity userEntityTo = getUserEntity();
        userEntityTo.setId(userToId);
        userEntityTo.setName("new name");
       
      
when(userRepository.findById(userEntityFrom.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(userEntityFrom));
 when(userRepository.findById(userEntityTo.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.of(userEntityTo);


//        when(userRepository.save(userEntityTo)).thenReturn(userEntityTo);
        userEntityTo.setFollowerOfEntity(null);
        userEntityTo.setFollowedByEntity(null);
        doReturn(userEntityTo).when(userRepository).save(any());
//        when(userEntityTo.getFollowedByEntity()).thenReturn(null);
        
//        doReturn(userEntityTo).when(userService).setFollower(any(), any());
        
        FollowerNotFoundException exception =
                assertThrows(FollowerNotFoundException.class, () -> userService.followUser(userFromId, userToId));

        assertEquals("Follower Not Found", exception.getMessage());
    }
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You're using mockito annotations in the class you are trying to test. This *not* how you should use Mockito.

Comment: You should declare a mock `UserRepository` in your test class and then inject it into your `UserService` instance when you create it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. UserRepository is already mocked at the top of the class.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code you've posted, but it looks as though the class  `UserRepository` is mocked in is `UserService`!

Comment: UserRepository in mocked in userService as userService is the one I'm testing and where the code I posted comes from.

Comment: The way that you use a mock `UserRepository` in `UserService` is by passing a mocked `UserRepository` to your `UserService` constrcutor when you create a `UserService` instance in your tests, not by using a `@Mock` annotation in the actual `UserService` class.

Comment: Thank you for your time putting this sample together. I've made the changes so my repository is now injected through the constructor for the service class. However, the original error I referred here is still there and I can't get the exception for null follower to throw. I've committed my code here if it may make it easier: https://github.com/francislainy/HelloTalk/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/hellotalk/service/UserServiceTest.java#L302 https://github.com/francislainy/HelloTalk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/hellotalk/service/impl/user/UserServiceImpl.java#L125

Comment: See the edit to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example (compressed into a single file) which explains what I have been trying to get across in the comments above:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

class MyService {
    private final MyRepository myRepository;

    MyService(MyRepository myRepository) {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public String doWork() {
        return myRepository.get().toUpperCase();
    }
}

class MyRepository {
    public String get() {
        return "a real thing from the DB";
    }
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyTests {
    @Mock
    MyRepository myRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void aTest() {
        when(myRepository.get()).thenReturn("something fake");
        assertEquals("SOMETHING FAKE", myService.doWork());
    }
}
```

The actual non-test code (which will live in `src/main/java`) is `MyService` and `MyRepository`. These classes have *no* reference to any test code.

`MyTests` is in `src/test/java`. It's the only part of your code which knows about mocks.

We can remove some of the "magic" by explicitly creating and injecting the mocks:

```
...
    MyRepository myRepository;

    MyService myService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        myRepository = mock(MyRepository.class);
        myService = new MyService(myRepository);
    }
...
```

Looking at the function you are testing we see:

```
        followingRequestEntities.add(followingRequestEntity);

        userEntityTo.setFollowedByEntity(followingRequestEntities);

        userEntityTo = userRepository.save(userEntityTo);
        
        
        if (userEntityTo.getFollowedByEntity() == null || userEntityTo.getFollowedByEntity().isEmpty()) {
            throw new FollowerNotFoundException("Follower Not Found");
        }
```

So as `followingRequestEntities` always contains one entry, `userEntityTo.getFollowedByEntity().isEmpty()` will *always* be false, no matter what your mocks return, and the exception can never be thrown.

You can use:

```
when(userRepository.findById(userEntityFrom.getId())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
```

and expect that `UserNotFoundException` will be thrown.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Is there perhaps any other error I could be asserting here to make sure I know how to verify if the saving has been done properly? Maybe asserting whether userEntity is null is enough?

Comment: Or maybe asserting for stack overflow exception or something like this?

Comment: Where do you think you'd get a StackOverflowError? If you don't find one or both of the users you throw a `UserNotFoundException`, but once you have both the users your code works. What does "verify if the saving has been done properly" mean?

Comment: I was getting a stack overflow error before because of the recursive relationship between followers and users and to do with the toString annotation, so I now excluded them from the followers entity. "verify if the saving has been done properly" means how to assert no error has happened under that operation. I'm trying to learn how to use TDD and as this is a void method, I'm a bit unsure what to assert here.

Comment: I've added an example of an exception you can get in my answer. You need to look at your code and explain to yourself under which *business* circumstances you expect the `FollowerNotFound` exception to be thrown. I cannot help you with that, as you are the one who understands the requirements. Then decide whether you've modeled that in your code.

Comment: That's great, thanks so much for your time helping me fix my understanding about what should happen here. Much appreciated.